# How to append columns instead of rows openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append, openpyxl

Currently using Openpyxl. I understand that append will print the output in excel in rows. I am trying to figure out if there is a function that can print the output in columns .eg:

```
headings = ['Name','Fruits']
ws.append(headings)

Name = ['John','Ben','Lily','Sarah']
Fruits = ['Orange','Apple','Grape','Peach']
```

Output in excel:

```
    A         B
 1 Name     Fruits
 2 John     Orange
 3 Ben      Apple
 4 Lily     Grape
 5 Sarah    Peach
```

Comment: Just use `ws.iter_cols()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information you are looking for is shown [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#write-a-workbook). The example shows how to iterate over columns and rows, which just ends up being simple grid/matrix logic.

```
from itertools import cycle

c = cycle([1, 2])

for idx in range(len(Name)):
    ws.cell(column=next(c), row=idx, value=Name[idx])
    ws.cell(column=next(c), row=idx, value=Fruits[idx])

# Column 1, Row 0 John
# Column 2, Row 0 Orange
# Column 1, Row 1 Ben
# Column 2, Row 1 Apple
# etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

Name = ['John','Ben','Lily','Sarah']
Fruits = ['Orange','Apple','Grape','Peach']

data=zip(Name,Fruits)
ws.append(['Name','Fruits'])
[ws.append(row_i) for row_i in list(data) ]
wb.save('fileaname')
```